# How can I automatically render a preview when the scene has changed?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

I have a split screen with my render on the right on very low sample rate so the render will happen quite quickly.  On the left, I have my 3d camera perspective for my modeling and object manipulation.  What I would like is to have the right side update the render when my objects on the left are changed automatically.  Is there a setting for this?  I already have the Update Automatically checked under the view menu however it doesn't seem to affect anything.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do the preview render in the viewport itself and set the viewport shading to "Rendered". Also type Numpad-0 to set the view and check "Border" to render only the important parts.

Everything you edit on the left side will cause the right screen to re-render.

[image: solution]